# How to check a mobile number that shouldn't have duplicated digits with Regex

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, string

I want to check if a mobile number has 11 digits, starts with zero and 3rd digit could be `0,1,2,3` and `9` only like `09123456789`. I used this pattern `^(09)([01239])\d{8}$` for this purpose, also I wanna check that 4th to 11th digits are not duplicated completely like `09123333333` or `090311111111`.

I use this Regex pattern: `^(09)([01239])(?!\2{8,})\d{8}$` to achieve this purpose but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Note that I have to use one Regex pattern exactly.

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Maybe `^09[01239](\d)(?!\1{7})\d{7}$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/PBvnGe/1))? Or `^09[01239](\d)(?!\1+$)\d{7}$`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, but the number like `09327777777` also matched. if it's possible to numbers like that not matched it'll be great.

Comment: Maybe `^09[01239]\d(\d)(?!\1{6})\d{6}$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks so much. It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^09[01239]\d(\d)(?!\1{6})\d{6}$
```

It matches

- `^` - start of string
- `09` - a `09` substring
- `[01239]` - a digit from the set
- `\d` - a digit
- `(\d)` - Group 1: a digit
- `(?!\1{6})` - no same digit as captured into Group 1 is allowed
- `\d{6}` - six digits
- `$` - end of string.